# JBoss 4.2 load javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory from xmlparserv2.jar?

Tags: spring, classloader, xerces, java-6, jboss-4.2.x

I'm using JBoss 4.2 and jdk6.

How can i only load javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory from *xmlparserv2.jar* in my webapp ?

When i used *-verbose:class*, javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory loaded by jdk6 :

```
[Loaded javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\lib\rt.jar]
```

and by xmlparserv2.jar

I have the following trace when Spring load. I use Spring core 3.1.3.

```
INFO  [STDOUT] ERROR [main] (ContextLoader.java:307) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/conf/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174
...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:29)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:89)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:70)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
... 149 more
```

MyEar
  - lib
      ...
      xmlparserv2.jar
      ...
  - META-INF
      application.xml
      jboss-app.xml
  + mywar.war

I have nothing in the WEB-INF/lib from the war. 
I can't remove xmlparserv2.jar because i need the oracle implementation of XMLNode in some jar.

Are there solutions without migrate JBoss to an older version ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a system property to force the specific Factory you want?

Quoting info from [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/jdbc103.htm)...

> You can also set a system property in your code:
>   System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory", "new-factory")
>   For example, if you are using the xerces parser, then new-factory is replaced by jorg.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.